# kik channel rejection for not handling scan-data and stickers using Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: botframework, kik

I used Microsoft Bot framework to create my bot and enabled the Kik channel. It got approved by Microsoft. However while submitting the same to the Kik bot store, they rejected my bot for not responding within 5 seconds to scan-data and Stickers . These are edge cases for me as my bot is not designed for it. I do not know how to handle this in Microsoft Universal bot (nodejs) framework.

I checked with Kik support, but they are unsure if Microsoft has made connectors for all their features. And they will not approve the bot without replying to all message types.

I can solve the problem using the native kik bot platform. But is there any way I can do this in the MS Universal bot framework itself? I posted this question on Skype bot forum and the moderator there requested me to post the same here hoping that someone from MS bot framework guides me. I searched for this on SO and did not find any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stickers sent to your Bot will come through as image attachments.  You just need to check the attachment field.

Scan-code values and links will be sent in the message body.

Comment: Thanks Lars. Kik wants the bot to respond to text, link, picture, video, scan-data, start-chatting and sticker messages. No issues with "Text" and "start-chatting" types and Based on your answer I presume picture, video & stickers could be checked as attachments. Can you also please confirm on "Link" type messages?

Comment: Support for scan-codes and links have been added and will be available next time we publish to production (usually in less than a week)